# Batch ogg vorbis transcode

Tags: bash, find, move

What I'm trying to do is simply make this command

```shell
find . -name "*flac" -exec oggenc -q 7 {} \;
```

spit the oggs out into whatever folder that I choose. I've tried just putting `~/vorbis` at the end of the command, but I get a predicate error:

```
find: possible unquoted pattern after predicate `-execdir'?
```

I've been through the "find manpage", and I understand that the `{}` at the end of `-q 7` is there to find `flac` files. So this is throwing me for a loop.

Anyone know what I have to add to that command so I can output oggs into chosen folder?

Thanks for reading and helping.

By the way, I did try:

```shell
find . -name "*flac" -exec oggenc -q 7 ~/vorbis {} \;
```

but that only spit the oggs into the folder with the flacs. Not a `~/vorbis` folder. I'm trying to keep folder name and structure put output it into a folder of my choosing (`~/vorbis`). And I 'm not asking for a full script. I'm just simply asking for somebody to explain how I can get what I'm trying to achieve.

Thank you!

Comment: Looking at your profile to understand at which level you need help. Wasn't there already a solution in your previous question? Seems like what was proposed there works for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch convert flac to ogg with ffmpeg](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/765583/batch-convert-flac-to-ogg-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: Also the command line you show doesn't seem to be the command line causing the error, so I'm not even sure that it's really possible to help you here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the command you would use to do this manually with one file, so we can understand what this `oggenc` thing expects. Once we know how it works for a single, specific file, then we can give you a `find` command for it.

Answer (score 2):

Using a sub shell, we can change the name of files and perform other commands, ensuring the output goes where we want.

```
mkdir -p ~/vorbis
find . -name "*flac" -exec sh -c 'oggenc -q 7 "$1" -o ~/vorbis/"${1%.*}".ogg' _ {} \;
```

> ...
> Opening with flac module: FLAC file reader Encoding
> "./summerbreezes.flac" to
> "/home/k/vorbis/./summerbreezes.ogg"  at quality 7.00    [ 99.0%] [ 0m00s remaining] -
>
> Done encoding file "/home/k/vorbis/./summerbreezes.ogg"
>
> File length:  1m 11.0s  Elapsed time: 0m 01.3s  Rate:         55.0760
> Average bitrate: 198.3 kb/s

```
ls ~/vorbis
alsowe.ogg        christmascard.ogg  love1.ogg          themanyone2.ogg  yourmom.ogg
An_Open_Door.ogg  GEDC4177.ogg       summerbreezes.ogg  winning.ogg
```

Comment: That's perfect! It's exactly what I wanted! It's converting the flac, and spitting them into ~/vorbis with the original file structure.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Now I'll have to break down your command so I can understand what you did. :) It works beautifully though.

Comment: Oh wait. If I would have used the -o command then that probably would have done it? I'm just now getting into scripting and things like that, so I'm curious is all

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the path leading up to `myfile.flac` you can have it spit them all out into one directory using the using an `-execdir` trick.

`find` with `-execdir` changes directory to the file before executing the command. It also changes `{}` to be the relative filename beginning with `./`.

```bash
find . -name '*.flac' -execdir oggenc -q 7 -o ~/vorbis/{}.ogg {} \;
```

So for this example, when it found `./path/to/myfile.flac` it would execute:

```bash
cd ./path/to
oggenc -q 7 -o ~/vorbis/./myfile.flac.ogg ./myfile.flac
```

> *(**Note:** At least with GNU findutils, the `./myfile.flac` is **really** the full path to the file or symlink it found, and NOT the relative path, but that shouldn't matter for OP's question)*